# json.loads(string) throws json.decoder.JSONDecodeError when trying to convert string to dictionary

Tags: python, json

I'm using the `requests` library to make an api call. The json response is then formatted as a string and sent as part of a result to my server as shown by the code snippet:

```
def get_and_send(url, method):
     resp = requests.request(url=url, method=method, **kwargs)
     result = f'{{ "status_code":{resp.status_code}, "content":{resp.json()} }}'
     send_to_server(result)
```

I intend to convert this result back to a dictionary object from the string result on the server.
 
The problem I have is that when I use `json.loads(result)` to convert the string to dictionary object, it throws the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/home/adipster/PycharmProjects/ScriptBackbone/ts_server/agent_thread.py", line 39, in run
    resp_data = self._task_formatter.format_response(response) # Formats the response
File "/home/adipster/PycharmProjects/ScriptBackbone/utils/task_formatter.py", line 26, in format_response
    response = self.get_dict_response(response.decode().strip())
File "/home/adipster/PycharmProjects/ScriptBackbone/utils/task_formatter.py", line 36, in get_dict_response
    raise exp
File "/home/adipster/PycharmProjects/ScriptBackbone/utils/task_formatter.py", line 34, in get_dict_response
    return json.loads(response)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 32 (char 31)
```

I understand that the error is because all my keys have to be in **double quotes** which is not the case when `resp.json()` is formatted to a string. 
Please can someone help out on how I could ensure that all the keys of my dictionary object are in double quotes?
Or any other alternative to this will be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: We need to see the specific response to speak to why it's not valid JSON.

Comment: ...or you could create it with `json.dumps()`, so it would be *guaranteed* to be valid JSON. That is: `result = json.dumps({"status_code": resp.status_code, "content": resp.json()})` (if `resp.json()` returns a native Python data structure, that is).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think you make a point there. I'll give your suggestion a go.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you should have posted that as an answer. It works like charm

Comment: It's in Henry's answer, which has my upvote. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is, as you point out, that if you just do string interpolation (with an `f`-string, for example), the quotes for strings in the JSON object will be single quotes, but JSON format requires double quotes.

To fix this you can use `json.dumps` which takes a JSON object (in Python) and converts it to a properly formatted JSON string. Edit thanks to Charles Duffy: You can avoid the `f`-string entirely by just creating the whole `result_data` object as a dictionary, then converting it to JSON all at once using `json.dumps`.

For example:

```
import json

def get_and_send(url, method):
    resp = requests.request(url=url, method=method, **kwargs)
    result_data = {
        "status_code": resp.status_code,
        "content": resp.json(),
    }
    result = json.dumps(result_data)
    send_to_server(result)
```

Comment: If we want `result` to be JSON, why use an f-string at all, rather than letting `json.dumps()` format the top-level as well?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh that's better